# Ubuntu only works with one screen (22.04 LTS)

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor

I changed something in the monitors.xml file located at /var/lib/gdm3/.config (I created it there before because my login screen was on the wrong monitor, I have two screens. This worked perfectly fine). I deleted the settings for one monitor. Since then, the screens freeze while booting (If I unplug the second monitor, everything works fine). I recreated the original file as it was before and changed everything that possibly makes problems, but still the same problem.

If you plug the second monitor in when logged in, everything still works - But then, the second monitor doesn’t show anything. If I go into settings and setup a dual-screen and apply, the second monitor disappears from the seconds and I still have only one monitor.

Also, my Nvidia settings application disappeared and some animations don’t work anymore (e. g. the dock sliding away normally).

If you have any questions, I‘ll answer them as good as I can, still a newbie.

Comment: I deleted the configuration for one monitor from the monitors.xml file located at /var/lib/gdm3/.config, I created that earlier because of different problems. If I change it back, same result - my screens keep freezing at bootup.

Comment: I‘m using Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed by reinstalling the Nvidia driver and deleting the existing monitor.xml file. After that, reconfigured my monitors via settings, everything works.